# Data Studio - Percentage Breakdown from multiple columns

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google Sheet connected to a Google Data Studio file. The data is structured as follows:

```
ID  Stream1 Stream2 Stream3 Total
001      10       5       5    20 
002       5      10      15    30 
003     100      20       5   125
004      50       0       0    50
```

Is there any way in Data Studio to produce a percentage breakdown of the `Total` field based on the various `Stream` fields? I was thinking of a Tree map chart, so Stream1 should have a box showing 8.8%, Stream2 13.3% etc.

Comment: This question **Needs Details** - See the 3 **[TO-DO]**: 1) Share a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [**TO-DO**] that reproduces a specific issue, using sample data, showing 2) Input values [DONE], 3) Expected output [**TO-DO**] 4) An issue / attempt at solving [**TO-DO**]. Without a specific use case ([Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/12182485)

Comment: Could you clarify on the calculation behind the figures in the statement: "*so Stream1 should have a box showing 8.8%, Stream2 13.3%*". If you could provide a Google Sheet (sample data) that has 1) the calculation behind the percentage figures 2) an example chart - if you are able to replicate the required chart in Google Sheets, it would help users understand what type of chart is required along with the expected output, so as to either replicate the chart and output in Google Data Studio, or provide an alternatives chart type that displays the data in the expected format / using those values

Answer (score 0):

In your DataStudio, Create a new field called "Stream1%".  In the definition of that field, code up the Formula as "Stream1/Total".   This will give you a new field you can add to your tables and charts.  You can now add "Stream1%" into your table and flag it as Numeric > Percentage.  You will now have a column the result you want.

[image]